# A word for the tracks a tractor leaves in a farm field?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a good translation of the German word "Fahrgasse." It describes the tracks a tractor leaves on a farm field. Usually parallel and evenly distributed, these tracks are used every time a farmer makes a pass over their growing field. In my technical dictionary, I found "tramline," but that does not seem to be used.

EDIT: These tracks are really **tramlines** as @Harry Gray describes them below: intentionally planned and left blank, so no crops are planted or flattened there. They are used and reused throughout the growing season for any cultivation measures needed on the field.

I am attaching a picture to show what I mean:

[image: "Fahrgassen" in a field]

<sup>Click the image for full-size</sup>

Comment: Note that *tramline* is *track* only in the sense of the railroad (or in the UK, railway), the parallel rails.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - Tramlines are for trams (streetcars) - trains run on _railway lines_.

Comment: @Paul, I've heard _tramlines_ used figuratively in this sense for such pairs of parallel wheelmarks without any confusion with literal rails.  We certainly used it on the farm where I grew up in Yorkshire (long before I ever saw an actual tram!)

Comment: @TobySpeight, Cool. Maybe it’s a British-ism that had escaped this Yank’s acquaintance.

Comment: @KateBunting, yes. I phrased my comment unclearly. I meant it as a simile.

Comment: One sense that might get lost here is the distinction between tracks made *by* a tractor versus trails *for* a tractor.  From "Fahrgassen" I get the latter sense - it's a path planned by the farmer and set aside for the tractor's use. From most of the suggestions, I get more of the former sense - there was a pristine field, and the farmer just happened to drive the tractor over this area and this is the chaos which happened in its wake. -- In other words, are you asking for a term to describe the "road" or the disturbance caused by the tractor?

Comment: The dictionaries say **tramline** or **driving lane**.

Comment: @R.M., I am asking for the "road" the farmer has planned for the tractor.

Comment: You cannot change the question once someone has answered. It seems you have found Harry Gray's answer to fit perfectly, you asked for a word and you got a compound noun. Please accept their answer as being correct. It's the grey checkmark that you should click on.

Comment: Googling "designing paths for tractors in a field" also brings up "AB lines" (primarily) and "traveler alleyways" (minimally) as terms connected to the science of field traffic pattern planning.  Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a literal translation, "fahrgasse" would roughly translate into English as "narrow tracks left after driving" - which I would render as "wheel tracks".

However, I am not sure what type of document you are referencing (however, you mentioned using a technical dictionary). As well, it may matter which version of English you are translating into - UK, US, etc.

I'm glad you uploaded a picture to clarify what you mean.

I would use "tracks", "wheel tracks", or "tractor wheel tracks".

However, if these tracks are part of a "controlled traffic farming" scheme, then they may be called "tramlines" or "controlled traffic lanes".

Consider these two references:
https://www.agriculture.com/machinery/farm-implements/sprayers/tramlines-boost-row-crop-field_230-ar34724

https://www.agric.wa.gov.au/soil-compaction/developing-controlled-traffic-tramline-farming-system

Comment: This is so helpful! Thanks! I am translating into American English, but it seems the concept of controlled-traffic farming or tramlining is new to U.S. farmers. In Germany, it has been around forever.

Comment: @Karina Of course, in translating, if the concept itself is unfamiliar to the audience, you might want to add some explanation, perhaps in a translator's footnote or parentheses.

Answer (score 17):

If you're talking about grooves or depressions that are created by the tractor often passing over the same ground, the best word is [ruts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rut).

EDIT: After the question was edited to include a picture, I'm going to say there's no ideal one-word English translation. "Rut" implies a significant depression in the ground, like erosion but linear. The picture shows tracks where crops are flattened, and could have been made in a single pass.

You used the word "track" several times in your question, and I think that's as close as English can get. Meaning simply "an impression made by something as it passed," whether animal footprints or the lines of tires. It would be reasonable to call the picture "tractor tracks."

Comment: If you check tractors and ruts, I think you will see that doesn't work.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the word most commonly used - I'd say something like "I walked along the ruts that the tractor had left during the last harvest"

Comment: BUT I think it's worth mentioning that "ruts" aren't exclusive to tractors. They're any depression in the ground that has been made over time (but not by water). I don't think English has a common term just for this

Comment: My family consists of many farmers, and rut is, by far, the term we'd most commonly use. As noted, this term is not defined specifically for this purpose and is not exclusive to tractor wheels, but it's quite rare to be in a situation where it's not obvious which rut you're talking about. In the unlikely case you'd need to explicitly distinguish, we'd use the phrase wheel rut. That said, rut implies a physical depression, and not just a path. If we're just talking about the vegetation being worn away, and there is no discernable depression, then we'd use the term path or tractor path.

Comment: https://tipsnotebook.deere.com/repair-ruts-or-tire-tracks/ No, not ruts.

Answer (score 13):

"Tractor tracks" would seem to be a fairly simple descriptive phrase:

> By entering fields on existing tractor tracks and paths, crop circle creators can help to disguise how the crop circle got there.  (Telegraph 2 Aug 2013)

This would be appropriate whether they are planned and created intentionally or not. (I'm not an arable farmer, but it seems to me that such tracks are used multiple times. The farmer will use the same tracks when harvesting as when planting, to avoid damage to the crop)

Answer (score 11):

You're correct **[tramline](https://www.bcpc.org/latest-news/tramline-thinking)** is the the right term for them, for **Britain and Ireland** that is, they are used for spraying and fertilising and are **incorporated into the field by design** when drilling so no crop is planted in those strips to avoid wasting seed, they will also be referred to as ruts post harvest as if they will get compacted & make a bit of a dip and will launch you out of your seat if you hit one at speed

"Furrows" are purely from ploughing,
"Tractor tracks" would describe the access route to a field or wheel marks left by movement and not by design,

Comment: Fair enough, although a few periods might be nice.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of this, and I wonder if that's because I'm American, or because it's simply not known outside of farming.

Comment: This is the right answer. The other answers refer to the tracks left in soft ground, etc, not these tracks left deliberately for access to the field.

Comment: The last sentence seems to be left with a hanging comma... and the end is missing? Please [edit] and complete the answer.

Comment: Is this a technical term?  (as it certainly isn't in general use) Can you give some evidence, or is this just a well known thing among arable farmers.

Comment: @JamesK, a Google search for *tramline farming* brings up a number of articles on controlled traffic (tramline) farming systems. One guide I glanced through was from 2004, so it may be a fairly recent use of the word.

Comment: @JamesK see https://www.bcpc.org/latest-news/tramline-thinking perhaps

Comment: Tramline is also the word I'd use, as a non-farmer who grew up in rural Yorkshire. I wouldn't say it was a technical term, but I wouldn't expect someone with no connection to the land at all to know it either.

Answer (score 1):

**tractor traces** would be another possibility.  A **trace** is a mark left by something that has passed over a surface, and **trace** has the further connotation that the path chosen was intentional, not random. Merriam-Webster offers the definition "a path, trail, or road made by the passage of animals, people, or vehicles".

> The farmer kept his tractor on the well-worn traces.

P.S. I upvoted **tractor tracks** because it would be immediately understood, which is an important virtue, though it might not be immediately understood as the reused pathways *through a planted field*. Tractor tracks could be marks in the mud on a rural lane. **tractor traces** stands a better chance of being understood as the evenly spaced paths in a planted field, absent additional description.

Comment: I could be wrong but... IMHO, a trace implies a certain lightness (of touch), or a delicate/faint line. Whereas tractors (and animals and people) are heavy and certainly do not leave a light mark behind them. So using "trace" for a tractor seems pretty incongruous. Plus, I don't think I've ever heard of "animal traces" (apart from snails).

Comment: Both of you have good points. Think of traces like in circuit boards. They are drawn intentionally and efficiently. However, "tracing their finger on the board" implies gracefulness. With the picture that OP supplied, it appears more "deliberate" and "graceful" than "driving a fourwheeler through mud". Also, from a larger scale (like in the picture), the tractor's non-delicate marks disappear.

Comment: @Greenonline You're focusing on only one meaning of **trace**.  See the Merriam-Webster definition, which refers to a "road". A road is not faint and delicate.